# Tengo problemas para aplicar un archivo js dentro de mi template en django

Tags: javascript, html, python, jquery, django

estoy aprendiendo la cosa con Django y estoy tratando de adaptar una plantilla bootstrap para la pagina index

Lo tengo de la siguiente manera

En el home.html

```html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
This is a starter template page. Use this page to start your new project from
scratch. This page gets rid of all links and provides the needed markup only.
-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
 
  

  <title>{{title}}</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&display=fallback">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'lib/AdminLTE-3.2.0/plugins/fontawesome-free-6.4.0/css/all.min.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'lib/AdminLTE-3.2.0/css/adminlte.min.css' %}">
  <script src="{% static 'lib/AdminLTE-3.2.0/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
  
  <script src="{% static 'lib/AdminLTE-3.2.0/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'lib/AdminLTE-3.2.0/js/adminlte.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'lib/sweetalert2-9.10.0/sweetalert2.all.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'js/functions.js' %}"></script>


  
  {% block head %}
  
  {% endblock %}
</head>


{% block body %}

{% endblock %}
</html>
```

En index.html

```html
{% extends 'home.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block head %}
    
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static 'homepage/images/favicon.png' %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'homepage/plugins/themefisher-font/style.css' %}">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'homepage/plugins/lightbox2/css/lightbox.min.css' %}">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'homepage/plugins/animate/animate.css' %}">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'homepage/plugins/slick/slick.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'homepage/css/style.css' %}">
<script src="{% static 'homepage/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>  
<script src="{% static 'homepage/plugins/parallax/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js' %}"></script>  
<script src="{% static 'homepage/plugins/lightbox2/js/lightbox.min.js' %}"></script>  
<script src="{% static 'homepage/plugins/slick/slick.min.js' %}"></script>  
<script src="{% static 'homepage/plugins/filterizr/jquery.filterizr.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'homepage/plugins/smooth-scroll/smooth-scroll.min.js' %}"></script>  
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCcABaamniA6OL5YvYSpB3pFMNrXwXnLwU"></script>
<script src="{% static 'homepage/plugins/google-map/gmap.js' %}"></script>  
<script src="{% static 'homepage/js/script.js' %}"></script>


{% endblock %}
{% block body %}

<body id="body">


  <div id="preloader">
    <div class='preloader'>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>


{% include 'header.html' %}

{% include 'principal.html' %}


<section class="service-2 section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">

      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <!-- section title -->
        <div class="title text-center">
          <h2>What Do We Offer</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
            adipisicing elit. Voluptates, earum. </p>
          <div class="border"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- /section title -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-4 text-center d-none d-md-block">
        <img loading="lazy" src="{% static 'homepage/images/about/member.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid inline-block" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="service-item">
              <i class="tf-ion-ios-alarm-outline"></i>
              <h4>Time Management</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vitae risus nec dui venenatis.</p>
            </div>
          </div><!-- END COL -->
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="service-item">
              <i class="tf-ion-ios-briefcase-outline"></i>
              <h4>Marketing Ideas</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vitae risus nec dui venenatis.</p>
            </div>
          </div><!-- END COL -->
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="service-item">
              <i class="tf-ion-ios-email-outline"></i>
              <h4>Mail Support</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vitae risus nec dui venenatis.</p>
            </div>
          </div><!-- END COL -->
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="service-item">
              <i class="tf-ion-ios-locked-outline"></i>
              <h4>Secure System</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vitae risus nec dui venenatis.</p>
            </div>
          </div><!-- END COL -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- End row -->
  </div> <!-- End container -->
</section> <!-- End section -->

<!--
Start About Section
==================================== -->
<section class="about-2 section" id="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <!-- section title -->
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="title text-center">
                    <h2>We Are Bingo Agency</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam reprehenderit accusamus labore iusto,
                        aut, eum itaque illo totam tempora eius.</p>
                    <div class="border"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /section title -->
        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6 mb-4 mb-md-0">
                <img loading="lazy" src="{% static 'homepage/images/about/about-2.png' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <ul class="checklist">
                    <li>Donec sed odio dui. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem laca quam venenatis vestibulum.</li>
                    <li>Aenean quam. Pellentesque ornare sem laca quam venenatis vestibulum.</li>
                    <li>Donec sed odio dui. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem laca quam venenatis vestibulum.</li>
                    <li>Etiam porta sem multipage evint landing magna mollis euismod a pharetra augue.</li>
                    <li>Aenean quam. Pellentesque ornare sem laca quam venenatis vestibulum.</li>
                </ul>
                <a href="about.html" class="btn btn-main mt-20">Learn More</a>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- End row -->
    </div> <!-- End container -->
</section> <!-- End section -->

<!--
Start Call To Action
==================================== -->
<section class="call-to-action section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-8 text-center">
                <h2>Let's Create Something Together</h2>
                <p>Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicudin bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum,
                    nesagittis sem nid elit. Duis sed odio sitain elit.</p>
                <a href="contact.html" class="btn btn-main">Contact Us</a>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- End row -->
    </div> <!-- End container -->
</section> <!-- End section -->

<!--
Start Counter Section
==================================== -->
<section class="counter-wrapper section-sm">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-8 text-center">
                <div class="title">
                    <h2>Award-Winning Agency</h2>
                    <p>Vestibulum nisl tortor, consectetur quis imperdiet bibendum, laoreet sed arcu. Sed condimentum iaculis ex, in faucibus lorem accumsan non. Donec mattis tincidunt metus. Morbi sed tortor a risus luctus dignissim.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <!-- first count item -->
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center ">
                <div class="counters-item">
                    <i class="tf-ion-ios-alarm-outline"></i>
                    <div>
                        <span class="counter" data-count="150">0</span>
                    </div>
                    <h3>Happy Clients</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end first count item -->

            <!-- second count item -->
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center ">
                <div class="counters-item">
                    <i class="tf-ion-ios-analytics-outline"></i>
                    <div>
                        <span class="counter" data-count="130">0</span>
                    </div>
                    <h3>Projects completed</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end second count item -->

            <!-- third count item -->
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center ">
                <div class="counters-item">
                    <i class="tf-ion-ios-compose-outline"></i>
                    <div>
                        <span class="counter" data-count="99">0</span>
                    </div>
                    <h3>Positive feedback</h3>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end third count item -->

            <!-- fourth count item -->
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center ">
                <div class="counters-item kill-border">
                    <i class="tf-ion-ios-bolt-outline"></i>
                    <div>
                        <span class="counter" data-count="250">0</span>
                    </div>
                    <h3>Cups of Coffee</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end fourth count item -->
        </div> <!-- end row -->
    </div> <!-- end container -->
</section> <!-- end section -->


{% include 'testimonial.html' %}
{% include 'blog.html' %}
{% include 'footer.html' %}


</body>

{% endblock %}
```

y en testimonial.html

```html
{% load static %}
{% block head %}
{% endblock %}
<section class="testimonial section" id="testimonial">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">               
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <!-- testimonial wrapper -->
                <div class="testimonial-slider">
                    <!-- testimonial single -->
                    <div class="item text-center">
                        <i class="tf-ion-chatbubbles"></i>
                        <!-- client info -->
                        <div class="client-details">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum nulla, soluta dolorum. Eos earum, magni asperiores, unde corporis labore, enim, voluptatum officiis voluptates alias natus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, officia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, quia?</p>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /client info -->
                        <!-- client photo -->
                        <div class="client-thumb">
                            <img loading="lazy" src="{% static 'homepage/images/client-logo/clients-1.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="client-meta">
                            <h3>William Martin</h3>
                            <span>CEO , Company Name</span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /client photo -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /testimonial single -->
            
                    <!-- testimonial single -->
                    <div class="item text-center">
                        <i class="tf-ion-chatbubbles"></i>
                        <!-- client info -->
                        <div class="client-details">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum nulla, soluta dolorum. Eos earum, magni asperiores, unde corporis labore, enim, voluptatum officiis voluptates alias natus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, officia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, quia?</p>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /client info -->
                        <!-- client photo -->
                        <div class="client-thumb">
                            <img loading="lazy" src="{% static 'homepage/images/client-logo/clients-2.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="client-meta">
                            <h3>Emma Harrison</h3>
                            <span>CEO , Company Name</span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /client photo -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /testimonial single -->
                
                    <!-- testimonial single -->
                    <div class="item text-center">
                        <i class="tf-ion-chatbubbles"></i>
                        <!-- client info -->
                        <div class="client-details">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum nulla, soluta dolorum. Eos earum, magni asperiores, unde corporis labore, enim, voluptatum officiis voluptates alias natus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, officia. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, quia?</p>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /client info -->
                        <!-- client photo -->
                        <div class="client-thumb">
                            <img loading="lazy" src="{% static 'homepage/images/client-logo/clients-3.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="client-meta">
                            <h3>Alexander Lucas</h3>
                            <span>CEO , Company Name</span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /client photo -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /testimonial single -->
                </div>
            </div>      <!-- end col lg 12 -->
        </div>      <!-- End row -->
    </div>       <!-- End container -->
</section>    <!-- End Section -->
```

Estoy tratando de seccionar, limpiar y personalizar poco a poco la plantilla index.html pero el problema lo tengo es en una funcion que tengo dentro de un archivo 'homepage/js/script.js'

```html
/**
 * WEBSITE: https://themefisher.com
 * TWITTER: https://twitter.com/themefisher
 * FACEBOOK: https://www.facebook.com/themefisher
 * GITHUB: https://github.com/themefisher/
 */

(function ($) {
  'use strict';

  /* ========================================================================= */
  /*    Page Preloader
  /* ========================================================================= */
  $(window).on('load', function () {
    $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function () {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });


  // navbarDropdown
    if ($(window).width() < 992) {
        $('#navigation .dropdown-toggle').on('click', function () {
            $(this).siblings('.dropdown-menu').animate({
                height: 'toggle'
            }, 300);
        });
  }
  
  //Hero Slider
  $('.hero-slider').slick({
    autoplay: true,
    infinite: true,
    arrows: true,
    prevArrow: '<button type=\'button\' class=\'prevArrow\'></button>',
    nextArrow: '<button type=\'button\' class=\'nextArrow\'></button>',
    dots: false,
    autoplaySpeed: 7000,
    pauseOnFocus: false,
    pauseOnHover: false
  });

/*AQUI ABAJO ESTA EL PROBLEMA*/

  $('.testimonial-slider').slick({
    infinite: true,
    arrows: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000
  });

  $('.hero-slider').slickAnimation();

  /* ========================================================================= */
  /*    Portfolio Filtering Hook
  /* =========================================================================  */
  // filter
  setTimeout(function(){
    var containerEl = document.querySelector('.filtr-container');
    var filterizd;
    if (containerEl) {
      filterizd = $('.filtr-container').filterizr({});
    }
  }, 500);

  /* ========================================================================= */
  /*    Testimonial Carousel
  /* =========================================================================  */
  //Init the slider



  /* ========================================================================= */
  /*    Clients Slider Carousel
  /* =========================================================================  */
  //Init the slider
  $('.clients-logo-slider').slick({
    infinite: true,
    arrows: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        infinite: true,
        dots: false
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false
      }
    }
    ]
  });

  /* ========================================================================= */
  /*    Company Slider Carousel
  /* =========================================================================  */
  $('.company-gallery').slick({
    infinite: true,
    arrows: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        infinite: true,
        dots: false
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 667,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false
      }
    }
    ]
  });

  /* ========================================================================= */
  /*    On scroll fade/bounce effect
  /* ========================================================================= */
  var scroll = new SmoothScroll('a[href*="#"]');

  // -----------------------------
  //  Count Up
  // -----------------------------
  function counter() {
    var oTop;
    if ($('.counter').length !== 0) {
      oTop = $('.counter').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > oTop) {
      $('.counter').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
          countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
        $({
          countNum: $this.text()
        }).animate({
          countNum: countTo
        }, {
          duration: 1000,
          easing: 'swing',
          step: function () {
            $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
          },
          complete: function () {
            $this.text(this.countNum);
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
  // -----------------------------
  //  On Scroll
  // -----------------------------
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    counter();

    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 50) {
      $('.navigation').addClass('sticky-header');
    } else {
      $('.navigation').removeClass('sticky-header');
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

En el marcador señalado no se me ejecuta esa funcion js de .testimonial-slider

En cambio si coloco esa funcion dentro de testimonial.html si me funciona, no entiendo por que.

Agradezco de antemano su ayuda, soy nuevo Django y no estaba familiarizado con javascript.

Answer (score 0):

No se si el archivo js es este que esta en el homehtml:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/functions.js' %}"></script>
```

o este otro archivo que está en el index:

```
<script src="{% static 'homepage/js/script.js' %}"></script>
```

Entiendo que en el template index.html no te está funcionando la función en cuestión no?

A mí en su momento a la hora de montar el inicio del proyecto en django también tuve problemas con que algunos archivos js no llegaban o no funcionaban en función de donde los ubicábamos, acabamos haciendo una practica que hasta ahora nos funciona:

```
{% block js %}
    <!-- Código JavaScript específico para esta página -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/mi_script.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Si el código JavaScript es común a varias páginas, puedes considerar el uso de un bloque común como home.html para incluirlo en todas ellas. Si el código JavaScript es específico de una página en particular, es mejor incluirlo directamente en el HTML de esa plantilla objetivo.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: <script src="{% static 'homepage/js/script.js' %}"></script> está en el archivo index.html